# Excel file overwritten instead of concat - Python - Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to contact all excel files and worksheets in them into one using the below script. It kinda works but then the excel file c.xlsx is overwritten per file, so only the last excel file is concated not sure why?

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import ntpath
import glob

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
os.chdir(dir_path)
cdf = None
for excel_names in glob.glob('*.xlsx'):
    print(excel_names)
    df = pd.read_excel(excel_names, sheet_name=None, ignore_index=True)
    cdf = pd.concat(df.values())
    cdf.to_excel("c.xlsx", header=False, index=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Idea is create list of `DataFrame`s in list comprehension, but because working with orderdict is necessary `concat` in loop and then again `concat` for one big final DataFrame:

```
cdf = [pd.read_excel(excel_names, sheet_name=None, ignore_index=True).values() 
       for excel_names in glob.glob('files/*.xlsx')]

df = pd.concat([pd.concat(x) for x in cdf], ignore_index=True)
#print (df)

df.to_excel("c.xlsx", index=False)
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190010/discussion-between-tak-and-jezrael).

Comment: Could you please check my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55182532/drop-duplicates-panadas-creates-more-rows-than-before

Comment: ya, not sure if do it, last time I kill 3 hours and no success :( Also question is downvoted, I think reason is no data, cannot test your problem.

Comment: problem is my solution working in win and not in mac, so hard testing

Comment: sorry, I just realised that the text I wrote in my question was deleted somehow. I've posted a new question with data here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55182678/drop-duplicates-panadas-creates-more-rows-than-before

Answer (score 0):

I just tested the code below.  It merges data from all Excel files in a folder into one, single, Excel file.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import glob
glob.glob("C:\\your_path\\*.xlsx")

all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob("C:\\your_path\\*.xlsx"):
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
    all_data = all_data.append(df,ignore_index=True)
print(all_data)
df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
df.shape
df.to_excel("C:\\your_path\\final.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

Comment: Could it also include the case when some of these excel files has multiple worksheets?

Comment: I've fixed the code to not do things every iteration that only need to be done at the end. Still no idea why `df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)` is needed if `all_data` is already a `DataFrame` -- looks redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using the below script which uses @ryguy72's answer but works on all worksheets as well as the header row.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob

all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob("my_path/*.xlsx"):
    df = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=None, ignore_index=True)
    cdf = pd.concat(df.values())
    all_data = all_data.append(cdf,ignore_index=True)
print(all_data)
df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
df.shape
df.to_excel("my_path/final.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet1')
```